# Do the results of the Elitzur-Vaidman quantum bomb tester experiment imply that counterfactual events affect what is observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, interference, wavefunction-collapse

Assuming that light travels as photons that can interfere with themselves while also only being detected as specific localized points, the results of the Elitzur-Vaidman quantum bomb tester experiment demonstrate that the interference of a photon can be affected without the photon itself being absorbed/affected by the object which affects the photon's interference. Does this mean that events that could have happened but did not ("counterfactual"), e.g. the photon being absorbed by the "bomb", are what determine what actually is observed, e.g. the photon being detected at Ddark? If so, how can this occur -- is the explanation for this, for now, strictly dependent on interpretation?
[image: Experimental Setup]

Comment: yes for now explanation strictly dependent upon interpretation: read my comments on this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/770225/366787

Comment: My personal understanding is the most reasonable explanation would be the existence of some kind of weak interaction with the live bomb which is not enough to explode it unless probability is decided in such a way to the photon's wave function collapse at the bomb and explode it. The physical nature of the wave function is further ratified by it only travelling at the maximum speed of causality and being momentous.